# Setter for std::vector

Tags: c++, vector, stl, std, setter

So I'm currently implementing a Design Pattern for my school project, that contains the class Model:

```
class Model {
    ...

    private:
    biosim::CreatureList list;

    public:
    biosim::CreatureList getList() const;
    void setList(const biosim::CreatureList& list);
};
```

CreatureList:

```
typedef std::vector<CreatureType> CreatureList;
```

I would like to set a vector containing my Creatures in this Class, so that I can access it later in a Presenter-Class.

First, I tried:

```
void Model::setList(const biosim::CreatureList& list) { this->list=list; }
```

but it gave me the following error:

```
'biosim::CreatureType &biosim::CreatureType::operator =(const biosim::CreatureType &)': attempting to reference a deleted function
```

After I googled I found a post where someone said I should try

```
void Model::setList(const biosim::CreatureList& list) { this->list=std::move(list); }
```

but it gave me the same error.

Right now I got it to compile by using

```
void Model::setList(const biosim::CreatureList& list) { this->list.assign(list.begin(), list.end()); }
```

but I'm not sure, if that is a good solution.
Could somebody explain to me, why the line above cause an error and the last one work? And more importantly: What would be the best way to do it?

Sorry if my English sucks, it's not my native language.

Comment: what is `biosom::CreatureList` ? If it cannot be copied, then you cant copy it and probably you shouldnt copy it

Comment: Also, using `std::move` on a `const` reference is obviously wrong.

Comment: The error message that you posted suggests that `biosim::CreatureType` is not copy-assignable. Does it have a non-copy-assignable member?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to store, take it by value:

```
void Model::setList(biosim::CreatureList list) { 
    this->list = std::move(list);
}
```

This will copy all of the values, so you need to provide a way to copy your `CreatureType` as well (that's what the `CreatureType::operator =(const biosim::CreatureType &)` error is about).

That being said, if you provide a way to store it, why not make the member public?

```
Model m;
m.list = list;
```

Comment: Thanks for a quick reply.
Is it good to make your members public? I just started learning C++ (as you can see by having to ask these kind of questions :D) but I learned Java in school and we were told to always make our members private and work with getters and setters

Comment: @Awesome36 Yes, it's okay to make members public if your setters are getters are trivial. If there's no internal invariant to be held, exposing members directly amounts to less and simpler code. There's a lot of information about that on SO.

Comment: @Awesome36 the Java advice is (mostly) from the mistaken belief that wrapping mutation in ceremony preserves encapsulation. That belief lead to the JavaBean style, which lots of Java tooling expects. Better advice is to make fields private and put the functions that change them in the class.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is, it seems, the elements of type CreatureType are not [trivially copyable.](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/TriviallyCopyable) So you should implement a copy / move constructor to be able to copy / move the data contained in the vector (than you can copy/move the vector, because vector implements the move semantics):

```
class CreatureType {
  public:
    CreatureType();                // default constructor
    CreatureType(const CreatureType& other);  // copy constructor
    CreatureType(CreatureType&& other); // move constructor
    CreatureType& operator=(const CreatureType& other); // copy operator
    CreatureType& operator=(CreatureType&& other); // move operator

  // ...
};
```

Check the ["The rule of three/five/zero".](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three)